How to set conditional props to manage different classes with Typescript
I'm a beginner and I have a question about conditionals. Hope to explain it clearly.
So, I have some props and based on different conditionals I want to apply different classes to div elements.
I'm pretty sure there is a better way to write it, also it's not working properly because the displayHeader condition is not respected and sometimes when I see the result on Storybook, it mixes classes from different conditions.
Here is my code, hope this makes my question clearer for you to help me.
<div
                className={cx({
                    "px-5 md:pb-5 md:pl-5 md:pr-0 w-full md:grow-0 md:shrink-0 md:basis-3/6":
                        align === "horizontal" &&
                        bodyLayout === "split" &&
                        size === "default" &&
                        displayHeader === true,
                    "px-5 md:pb-5 md:pl-5 md:pr-0 w-full md:grow-0 md:shrink-0 md:basis-2/5":
                        align === "horizontal" &&
                        bodyLayout === "golden" &&
                        size === "default" &&
                        displayHeader === true,
                    "px-5 w-full": align === "vertical" && size === "default" && displayHeader === true,
                    "px-5 pt-5 md:py-5 md:pl-5 md:pr-0 w-full md:grow-0 md:shrink-0 md:basis-3/6":
                        align === "horizontal" &&
                        bodyLayout === "split" &&
                        size === "default" &&
                        displayHeader === false,
                    "px-5 pt-5 md:py-5 md:pl-5 md:pr-0 w-full md:grow-0 md:shrink-0 md:basis-2/5":
                        align === "horizontal" &&
                        bodyLayout === "golden" &&
                        size === "default" &&
                        displayHeader === false,
                    "w-full px-5 pt-5": align === "vertical" && size === "default" && displayHeader === false,

                    "px-6 md:pb-6 md:pl-6 md:pr-0 w-full md:grow-0 md:shrink-0 md:basis-3/6":
                        align === "horizontal" && bodyLayout === "split" && size === "large" && displayHeader === true,
                    "px-6 md:pb-6 md:pl-6 md:pr-0 w-full md:grow-0 md:shrink-0 md:basis-2/5":
                        align === "horizontal" && bodyLayout === "golden" && size === "large" && displayHeader === true,
                    "w-full px-6": align === "vertical" && size === "large" && displayHeader === true,
                    "px-6 pt-6 md:py-6 md:pl-6 md:pr-0 w-full md:grow-0 md:shrink-0 md:basis-3/6":
                        align === "horizontal" && bodyLayout === "split" && size === "large" && displayHeader === false,
                    "px-6 pt-6 md:py-6 md:pl-6 md:pr-0 w-full md:grow-0 md:shrink-0 md:basis-2/5":
                        align === "horizontal" &&
                        bodyLayout === "golden" &&
                        size === "large" &&
                        displayHeader === false,
                    "w-full px-6 pt-6": align === "vertical" && size === "large" && displayHeader === false,
                    hidden: bodyLayout === "no-image",

                    "p-0 w-full md:w-md:grow-0 md:shrink-0 md:basis-3/6":
                        align === "horizontal" && bodyLayout === "split" && cardBackground === "transparent",
                    "p-0 w-full md:grow-0 md:shrink-0 md:basis-2/5":
                        align === "horizontal" && bodyLayout === "golden" && cardBackground === "transparent",
                    "w-full p-0": align === "vertical" && cardBackground === "transparent",

                    "px-5 md:pb-5 md:pl-5 md:pr-0 w-full h-auto md:w-[220px]":
                        align === "horizontal" && bodyLayout === "free-size",
                })}
            ></div>

<div
                className={cx("flex flex-col justify-center self-stretch flex-1", {
                    "px-5 pb-5 pt-3 md:pb-5 md:pr-5 md:pl-4 md:pt-0":
                        displayHeader === true &&
                        align === "horizontal" &&
                        size === "default",
                    "px-5 pb-5":
                        displayHeader === true &&
                        align === "horizontal" &&
                        size === "default" &&
                        bodyLayout === "no-image",
                    "px-5 pb-5 pt-3 md:py-5 md:pr-5 md:pl-4 md:pt-0":
                        displayHeader === false &&
                        align === "horizontal" &&
                        size === "default",
                    "p-5": 
                        displayHeader === false && 
                        align === "horizontal" &&
                        size === "default" && 
                        bodyLayout === "no-image",
                    "px-5 pb-5 pt-3": align === "vertical" && size === "default",

                    "px-6 pb-6 pt-4 md:pb-6 md:pr-6 md:pl-5 md:pt-0":
                        displayHeader === true &&
                        align === "horizontal" &&
                        size === "large",
                    "px-6 md:pb-6":
                        displayHeader === true &&
                        align === "horizontal" &&
                        size === "large" &&
                        bodyLayout === "no-image",
                    "px-6 pb-6 pt-4 md:py-6 md:pr-6 md:pl-5 md:pt-0":
                        displayHeader === false &&
                        align === "horizontal" &&
                        size === "large",
                    "p-6":
                        displayHeader === false &&
                        align === "horizontal" &&
                        size === "large" &&
                        bodyLayout === "no-image",
                    "px-6 pb-6 pt-4": align === "vertical" && size === "large",

                    "pt-3 md:pl-4":
                        align === "horizontal" && cardBackground === "transparent",
                    "pt-3": align === "vertical" && cardBackground === "transparent",
                })}
            ></div>

Not sure if it is helpful but these are the props options:
size?: "default" | "large";
align?: "horizontal" | "vertical";
displayHeader?: boolean;
displayFooter?: boolean;
cardBackground?: "light" | "shade" | "transparent";

type BodyLayout = "split" | "golden" | "no-image";
bodyLayout?: BodyLayout;

Thanks in advance for your help.

Hi. Can't say anything about the content itself since it's pretty hard to follow. As for the structure, I'd probably move it to a dedicated file - classNameResolver let's say. Also, I'd break the class names into something more granular. so instead of chaining multiple conditions and apply the full list of classes, each condition applies to specific class. I hope it's clear. This is will make your code way more clear and easier for debug. As for your question, if can create a working example, it will be easier for us to help
